# Display result of php date range serach in same html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to do a search in my database base on date range.I can get a result in mysql console:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as sum from serviceces where date_of_service between '2014-11-06' and '2014-111-    12';
```

//so in my form

```
<?php
    include_once('../../libs/search/search_sales_by_date.php');
    include_once('../../libs/search/total_sales.php');
?>
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>search by dates</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <?php
            if(isset($error)) {
                echo $error;
            }
            if(isset($success)) {
                echo $success;
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <h3>Search Sales</h3>
        <p>From</p>
        <form method="GET" action="search_sales_by_dates.php">
            <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="from_date" id="field1"></p>
            <p>To</p>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="to_date" id="field2"></p><br />
            <input type="submit" value="search" name="submit" id="submitdata">
        </form>
```

//search.php

```
<?php
    //$total_by_date_range = "";
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { 
        include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
        $init = new ManageServices();  
        $date_from = (isset($_GET['from_date']) ? $_GET['from_date'] : null);
        $date_to = (isset($_GET['to_date']) ? $_GET['to_date'] : null);

        if(empty($date_from) && empty($date_to)) {
            $error = "No search query";  
        } elseif(empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {
            $error = "Specify your end date search";
        } elseif(!empty($date_from) && empty($date_to)) {
            $error ="Specify your start date search";
        } else {
            $total_by_date_range = 0;
            $total_by_date_range = $init->getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to);
            if($total_by_date_range== 1) {
                $success ="Total calculated base on your search: ".$total_by_date_range;
            } elseif (!$total_by_date_range) {
                $error = "error";
            } else {
                $error = "Record not found due to some errors";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

//class.ManageServices.php

```
function getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to) {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_of_date_range FROM services WHERE
    date_of_service between '".$date_from."' and '".$date_to."'");    
    $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
    $result = $query->fetch();
    return $result; 
}
```

My problem is, if I do an echo $total_date_by_range in my form,it shows nothing ,doing a vardump($total_by_date_range) displays null.What's wrong with my code? Also I need to display the result on the same form. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I put  at the top of form since it will display notice unidentified index.....everytime I submit the button.

Updates..

vardump($total_by_date_range) results in

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  'sum_of_date_range' => null
  0 => null
```

why does 'sum_of_date_range' null?

Comment: Have you used the console to check if (after changing values) the date input values are empty?

Comment: already check.its working in console.@Marco Mura, maybe some of my php codes is not working.I tried vardump and var_export($total_date_by_range) and both results null;if i remove error reporting on html form, it show unidentified index $total_date_by_range notice..

Comment: so in search_sales_by_dates.php (form action) you do not see the $_GET values?

Comment: i cant see the $_GET values.I tried to echo $total_date_by_range after the form and it shows '0.00'.'0.00' is the default value in amount column in mysql

Comment: try to print $_GET['from_date'] directly on head of php code on search.php, try all the $_GET even -> $_GET['submit'] or isset($_GET['submit'])

Comment: change the method to POST and change $_GET to $_POST maybe on $_GET you will not obtain the submit button click